# how to table Reload ios when recieving response Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, httprequest

Hi My problem is that i am getting a response from a web service and when i parse it and add to table and reload the table view it is not refreshing . Although if i call the [table reload] in keyboard is shown it gets updated there. Could someone tell me if im missing anything

This is what i am trying to do

```
- (void) longPoll {
//create an autorelease pool for the thread
   @autoreleasepool {

    NSLog(@"polling");
   VSAppDelegate *var = (VSAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //compose the request
NSError* error = nil;

NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;


    //send the request (will block until a response comes back)
NSData* responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request                                           returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"polling response is  %d",response.statusCode);

//pass the response on to the handler (can also check for errors here, if you want)
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataReceived:) withObject:responseData waitUntilDone:YES];
}

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}

- (void) startPoll {

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(longPoll) withObject: nil];
}
 - (void) dataReceived: (NSData*) theData 
{
    //process the response here
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"polling data is %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
      NSLog(@"polling data is %@",[[theData base64EncodedString]base64DecodedString]);
   NSDictionary *notifDic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //VSViewControllerSplit *split = [[VSViewControllerSplit alloc]init];
    [self RecieveFunction:notifDic];

}
```

Comment: Did you check that your data source has the correct data and is it correctly linked to your tableview?

Comment: Yes it is correct the problem is i add it to the table and call it just after that but nothing happens. Yes the table view is not nil because i am able to see it when i debug the code . Also when i click the text field it goes to the keyboard did show notification where im calling [table reload data] and there its getting reloaded

Comment: post ur code what u have tried first, then only we can able to find the problem

Comment: Do you receive the data on a background thread?

Comment: Yes but im processing the data on a main Thread

Comment: try to print the values in ur log and check whether they are getting printed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           [tablrView reloaddata];

                          });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dataReceived` method doesn't appear to be calling `reloadData`. I'll assume that `RecieveFunction` method does, though, but you should confirm that. It's hard to say without seeing `RecieveFunction`.

The more fundamental issue would appear to be that `dataReceived` method is creating a new instance of `VSViewControllerSplit`, calling its `RecieveFunction` method, and then letting this new `VSViewControllerSplit` instance fall out of scope (and if using ARC, get deallocated unless you pushed to it, presented it, etc.). You presumably don't want to create a new `VSViewControllerSplit` every time `longPoll` calls `dataReceived`, but rather just reference the existing instance.

Comment: Hi yeah thanks I did that keeping the function in the vsviewcontrollersplit but the problem is my delegates nil when I'm refreshing it from recieve data and after that it comes back

Comment: @BackStabber Yes, because you instantiate a new VC every time, it would be `nil`. (That's why I earlier asked about the table view being `nil`.) You didn't say in which class your above code snippet was implemented, but if it's not the `VSViewControllerSplit`, itself, then you should probably create a `weak` property to hold a reference to the existing `VSViewControllerSplit` instance rather than creating a new one every time.

Comment: im still getting datasoure as nil in     dataRecieved :(

Comment: @BackStabber I'm possible for us to diagnose on the basis of the information provided. But was the `dataSource` property set initially (either in IB or in `viewDidLoad`? And you've removed the re-instantiation of `VSViewControllerSplit` object?

Comment: updated the code above and ya have set the datasource in `viewdidLoad` also only till the process completes i get it as not null . I have a workaround which sees the size of the datasource and then refreshes the table and is based on a timer event(started in `viewDidLoad`) which is repetitive. Although it will only refresh when the table data increases but  it gives an extra load on my mind also and i really need to solve this in a proper way